# Pyhton import from parent folder when executing script

Tags: python, import, module

I have a project with the following structure:

```
/Project
    __init__.py
    importable.py
    /tests
        test.ipynb
```

inside `importable.py` I have define a class `MyClass` and I want to import `MyClass` into `test.ipynb`.

I want the import to work when I execute test.ipynb **as a script** so a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder) would not work as far as I understood, since relative imports don't work when executing a file as a script, am I correct?

Also in the linked question the proposed answer imports the whole module whereas I want to import just one class.

I tried going down `sys.path` and it works but leaves a lot of code at the beginning of files and the project robustness would suffer, moreover I'd rather modify PYTHONPATH but I tried and I think I did something wrong.

From what I have understood even if it is not in the PYTHONPATH python always tries to resolve modules to the working dir, right?

Are there cons to adding cwd/.. to the PYTHONPATH? Is it a bad practice?